# Proof of this "Differenting Under the Integral" Generalization

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I refer to Theorem 3 at: http://planetmath.org/differentiationundertheintegralsign

[image]

I have two questions:

Q1) Why is Theorem 3 considered a generalization of Theorem 2? It seems to me that $f(x,\omega)$ is an absolutely continuous function of $x$ for almost all $w\in\Omega$ is a pretty strong condition, since for Theorem 2 we don't even require for $f$ to be continuous, just Lebesgue-integrable.

Q2) Can anyone provide a proof (or reference to a proof) for Theorem 3? I have been searching but can't find one.
(For those who are interested, Theorem 2's proof can be found in e.g. Folland pg 56.)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: write the limit definition of $d/dx \int_\Omega f(x,\omega)d \omega$ and use the absolute continuity and  integrability  assumption for exchanging $\lim$ and $\int$. And the theorem 2 assumption is stronger, it states that $|\partial f(x,\omega)/\partial x| \leq\Theta(\omega)$ where $\Theta(\omega)$ is integrable

Answer (score 1):

Only for Q1:

1. Theorem 2 requires $f$ to be integrable for each $x$. Theorem 3 requires $f$ to be integrable for almost all $x$. Both require $f$ to be measureable although this is not stated explicitly in theorem 2.
2. Theorem 2 requires $f$ to be differentiable everywhere with respect to $x$ for almost all $\omega$, while theorem 3 only requires f to be absolutely continuous for almost all $\omega$. It's possible to show that abolute continuous implies differentiability almost everywhere.
3. If the property of theorem 2 holds, i.e. that the derivative with respect to $x$ is bounded by a integrable function independent of $x$ it is easy to see that the integral in theorem 2 is finite (i's bounded by $(b - a) c$, where $c$ is the integral of $\Theta$).

Comment: +1 thanks. But I am confused for point 2, since absolutely continuous implies differentiability a.e., doesn't this mean Theorem 3 requires a stronger condition?

Comment: Hm, yeah, I've just seen this too. I think functions which are absolutely continuous everywhere are differentiable almost everywhere. I'm not sure right now about what happens if $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere.

I'll think about it and reply late and 1. and 3. are obviously stronger conditions.

Comment: theorem 2 ask for differentiability for **every** $x$ on almost every $\omega$ "section".

theorem 3 hypothesis imply only differentiability for **almost every** $x$ on almost every $\omega$ "section".

Comment: Oh, you're right, I fixed it. The question remains open. There are differentiable functions which are not absolutely continuous.

Comment: yes, strictly speaking th3,2 assumption is not weaker than th2,2 assumption since absolute continuity also imply some boundeness on the derivative. However this boundeness is recovered by th2,3 assumption if i'm not wrong. So th3 is indeed stronger than th2.

Comment: Absolute continuity implies integrability of the derivative. th2,3 implies boundedness of the derivative and therefore integrability on bounded domains. This might be sufficient already, but i don't know...